# Looking for T-SQL scripts to delete a SQL Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

If I know the database server name, instance name and the SQL Server job name, how to delete a SQL Server job by its name in a simple way? I am writing scripts which will be called by sqlcmd to delete SQL jobs.

Appreciate if anyone could show me a sample? :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
USE msdb;

GO

EXEC sp_delete_job
    @job_name = N'NightlyBackups' ;

GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`sp_delete_job`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx):

```
[srv].[master].[dbo].sp_delete_job @job_name = 'MyJob'
```

So this four part name only works with linked servers. Otherwise, you'll have to connect to the server, and run that command against it (with everything right of `[dbo].`.

Comment: How about just execute USE msdb ;
GO

EXEC sp_delete_job
    @job_name = $(Job name here);
GO

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that you can just use SSMS, choose the job, right-click and pick "Delete", and then use the Script button at the top of the dialog box to generate a script like the ones suggested here.